# Highlight line(s) containing search word

Tags: vim

I am aware that it is possible to configure vim to highlight all matches for the searched word.

But, is it possible to highlight the entire line(s) on which the searched for word is found? If so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exact solution depends probably on your goal:

Do you want to make the matched lines stand out a little more?

Do you want to know the line numbers for further use?

Do you want to act directly on those lines?

You could use the quickfix window to list the lines containing a match:

```
:vim! foo . | copen
```

You could use the `:global` command to list or act on every line containing a match:

```
:g/foo<CR>          " list the lines
:g/foo/<Ex command> " act on each line
```

Comment: +1 This is excellent. I just wanted to view the matched lines as group so the `:g/foo` is perfect.

Answer (score 11):

If you generally want the current line highlighted:

```
:set cursorline
```

If you just want the searches highlighted, the only easy way is by extending the search pattern to cover the entire line:

```
:set hlsearch
:let @/ = '.*'.@/.'.*'
```

Note that on `n` / `N`, the cursor will now jump to the beginning of the line, not the matched word. Also, you won't be able to do `:%s//...` substitutions of the matched word (without repeating the search pattern) any more.

Comment: @dominikz: Yes, whenever the search pattern changes. That doesn't mean you have to type this every time; I would define a mapping, or even hook into command-line editing, so if you conclude a search by pressing (for example) `<S-CR>` instead of `<CR>`, it will automatically extend the pattern.

Answer (score 3):

```
:set hlsearch
```

will [highlight](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_all_search_pattern_matches) the searched-for word.

Note also that you can [highlight your current line](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_current_line) i.e. the line your cursor is on. So when you move between matches, the complete line you move to will be highlighted.

Comment: Thanks, my question may not have been clear. I am aware of the word highlighting functionality but was asking if it is possible to highlight the line on which the searched for word is found?

Comment: Sure. I've amended to give an answer that gets you some way (if not completely) to what you want

Comment: +1. Thanks, didn't know of that. If no better answer appears I'll accept in a day or so.

Answer (score 0):

You may install this plugin [highlight.vim](https://github.com/vim-scripts/highlight.vim). One of the shortcut key `<C-h><C-j>` allowed you to highlight the line contains the previous search pattern.

Answer (score -1):

Please use this:

To highlight all the search pattern matches in a file set the following option:

```
:set hlsearch
```

To disable the highlighting temporarily, use:

```
:nohlsearch
```